# Replace second space with new line sed

Tags: awk, sed

I have data in below format:

```
1234 2 3457 2 23454 12 98769 1 123 20
```

I am trying to get the data in below format:

```
1234 2 
3457 2 
23454 12 
98769 1 
123 20
```

I tried using:

```
sed -E -e 's/[[:blank:]]+/\n /2' test.txt
```

but this didn't work.

Comment: Thing is that your approach did not work because you are replacing just once, on the 2nd match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`Awk`** solution:

```
awk '{ for(i=1; i<=NF; i+=2) print $i, $(i+1) }' test.txt
```

- `i+=2` - the step of increment (processing 2 items per one iteration)

The output:

```
1234 2
3457 2
23454 12
98769 1
123 20
```

Answer (score 6):

### Simply use [printf](/questions/tagged/printf) shell builtin :

```
$ printf '%d %d\n' 1234 2 3457 2 23454 12 98769 1 123 20
```

### Or with [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) or [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) (credit to fedorqui)  :

```
$ echo "1234 2 3457 2 23454 12 98769 1 123 20" |
    sed -E 's/([0-9]+\s[0-9]+)\s/\1\n/g'

$ echo '1234 2 3457 2 23454 12 98769 1 123 20' |
    grep -oE '[0-9]+\s[0-9]+'
```

### Or with [tr](/questions/tagged/tr) and [paste](/questions/tagged/paste) (credit to glenn jackman) :

```
$ echo "1234 2 3457 2 23454 12 98769 1 123 20" |
    tr -s '[:blank:]' '\n' |
    paste -d" " - -
```

### Or with [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) :

```
$ echo '1234 2 3457 2 23454 12 98769 1 123 20' |
    perl -lne 'print for /(\d+\s+\d+)+/g'
```

### Output :

```
1234 2
3457 2
23454 12
98769 1
123 20
```

### Note :

If you'd had the [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) tag, we could had removed one pipe `|` using the *bashism* :

```
command <<< 'foo bar base'
```

> It's a *here-string*. Similar to here documents: The word after `<<<` and a newline are passed to the standard input of a command. Syntax: `command <<< "some sentence"` (Like `echo "some sentence" | command`, but without the overhead of the subshell)

### A bit of benchmark :

```
$ time printf '%d %d\n' 1234 2 3457 2 23454 12 98769 1 123 20

real    0m0,000s
user    0m0,000s
sys     0m0,000s
```

Comment: or with sed → `sed -r 's/[0-9]+\s[0-9]+ /&\n/g' <<< "bla"`

Comment: or `tr -s '[:blank:]' '\n' <<<"$data" | paste -d" " - -`

Comment: And using `grep` → `grep -oE '[0-9]+\s[0-9]+'`. That is, print only the matches of "number space number".

Answer (score 2):

Following `xargs` solution may help you.

```
xargs -n2 < Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
1234 2
3457 2
23454 12
98769 1
123 20
```

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/\s/\n/2;P;D' file
```

Replace the second white space by a newline. Print up to and including the newline, then delete what was printed. Repeat until the pattern space is empty then replenish the pattern space with the next line and repeat.